# python django id to hex

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to take the default ID key from the django model turn it into hexadecimal and display it on a page when the user sumbits the post, I've tried several of methods with no success can anyone point me in the right direction?

views.py

```
def post_new(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'books_log/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Can supply more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's hex function is all you need here, but the problem is you can't call it directly from your template. So the solution is to add a method to your model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

   def to_hex(self):
       return hex(self.pk)
```

Then in your template

```
 {{ my_object.to_hex }}
```

Comment: {{ my_object.to_hex() }} remove the () from my_object.to_hex
This worked like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to have helped.